# How can I write this postgreSQL rank()-query?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with soccer-teams with the following column names:

```
Teamname  --- Region  ---  Score
```

I want to rank my soccer-teams by score. I managed to do do a RANK() query like this:

```
SELECT teamname, region, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY score) 
as rankingTotal FROM soccerscoretable
```

Now I want to get a rank by Region as well as the total rank.

The expected result of the query is an answer which gives me the following:

- Teams name
- Region
- Score
- Total ranking
- Ranking by the teams region.

This is how my attempt to write that query looks now. **And it does not work. I am lost in the woods.**

```
SELECT teamname, region, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY score) as rankingtotal, rankingRegion
FROM soccerscoretable,
(SELECT RANK() OVER(ORDER BY score) as rankregion 
 from soccerscoretable where region = 'The regions name') AS rankingRegion
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8a0fd/1)

**Sample data:**

```
| teamname | region  | score |
|----------|---------|-------|
| team5    | region3 | 50    |
| team1    | region1 | 100   |
| team2    | region2 | 200   |
| team4    | region2 | 250   |
| team3    | region1 | 300   |
```

**Expected output:**

```
| teamname | region  | score | rankingtotal | rankingregion |
|----------|---------|-------|--------------|---------------|
| team5    | region3 | 50    | 1            | 1             |
| team1    | region1 | 100   | 2            | 1             |
| team2    | region2 | 200   | 3            | 1             |
| team4    | region2 | 250   | 4            | 2             |
| team3    | region1 | 300   | 5            | 2             |
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: please chose one db vendor, provide sample data and expected reslut

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Thank you for the plain-text-table-tip! Now I've added sample data, expected output and a link to SQL-fiddle.

Comment: Lookup `PARTITION BY` in your manual.